# Get a list element with condition

Tags: python

suppose we have two  lists of list shown below:

```
A = [['Jake', 'Tall', 90], 
     ['Dunne', 'Tall', 80], 
     ['Steve', 'Not Tall', 70], 
     ['Robert', 'Tall', 70], 
     ['Emily', 'Not Tall', 85]]

B = [['Tall', 10], ['Not Tall', 20], ['Almost Tall', 30], ['Very Short', 40]]
```

So the list `A` will append a new element on its list that from additional of its third element and the second element  of `B` based on what is the second element of `A`, if its `'Tall'` it will be added with `10` and otherwise `20` if `'Not Tall'`.

For ease of understanding, lets take an example for `A[0]`, we see that `A[0][1] = 'Tall'` so the element that we will append to `Jake` is `90 + 10` and so on for other `A` elements.

In the end, what I expected for `A` list is:

```
A = [['Jake', 'Tall', 90, 100], 
     ['Dunne', 'Tall', 80, 90], 
     ['Steve', 'Not Tall', 70, 90], 
     ['Robert', 'Tall', 70, 80], 
     ['Emily', 'Not Tall', 85, 105]]
```

What I've tried:

```
for row in A:
    if row[1] == 'Tall':
        row = row.append(row[2] + B[0][1])
    elif row[1] == 'Not Tall':
        row = row.append(row[2] + B[1][1])
```

But you know, its not an efficient way since if we add more list in `B`
Need helps for an efficient way for this problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This would be somewhat easier if `B` was a dictionary, instead of a list.

Comment: yeah I know, but for this  problem, B must be a list too

Comment: If you are interested in an efficient way, you should also think about changing your data model (i.e. not save everything in lists).

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [a + [(a[2]+dict(B)[a[1]])] for a in A]
```

[Run this code](https://tio.run/##XY4xD4IwEIV3fsVtbQMDYIw4OEB0cXBQt8sNVSE2YkuaasKvr4AM1Vtect/3ktf17m70wvsSNoDI9vJRswTYWbbtkOuUEohgPGTbl9YhLEJ4cvV7ggfjYBZWoXA0l9q6oP5Dd0/V9n/1YkkURdV32PzLxhKGVp6O1jRfQgzIJeYU39TV8UqgxIxIEDTGggSloRzkzirteCm8/wA)

Basically this code iterates over the sub-lists in A and looks up in B what to do to them, using a list comprehension to build a new list out of them.

Comment: some more explanations would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate it like this:

```
def getIndex(b, desc):
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if b[0] is desc:
            return i

for i in range(len(A)):
    A[i].append(B[getIndex(B, A[1])][1] + A[i][2])
```

Of course there must be some shortcuts such as lambda expressions, yield, etc. but this would be the foundational solution.

Comment: @JON PANTAU I did edited my last comment but since it was deleted by you, I had to add another one.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with *list comprehension*

```
a = [i + [i[-1] + j[-1]] for i in a for j in b if i[1] in j]
```

> ```
> [['Jake', 'Tall', 90, 100], ['Dunne', 'Tall', 80, 90], ['Steve', 'Not Tall', 70, 90], ['Robert', 'Tall', 70, 80], ['Emily', 'Not Tall', 85, 105]]
> ```

Expanded loop:

```
new_a = []

for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if i[1] in j:
            new_a.append(i + [i[-1] + j[-1]])
```